# Apache commons config ignores outermost XML tag? Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: xml, apache-commons-config

Ok, I used to use apache commons config years ago a little, and have probably forgotten some things.

I'm a little baffled by what's going on, and it seems counter-intuitive to me.

So, here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
    XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("config/base-config.xml");
    config.setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());
    List<Object> recipients;
    recipients = config.getList("emailRecipients/recipient");
    System.out.println("Recipients: " + recipients.size());
    for (Object recipient : recipients) {
        System.out.println("\tRecipient: " + recipient);
    }
}
```

And here's my xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<emailRecipients>
    <recipient>me@email.com</recipient>
    <recipient>you@email.com</recipient>
</emailRecipients>
```

However, my code won't read the recipient tags as I expect.

Instead, I have to modify my config file to look like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arbitrary-outer-tag>
    <emailRecipients>
        <recipient>me@email.com</recipient>
        <recipient>you@email.com</recipient>
    </emailRecipients>
</arbitrary-outer-tag>
```

So, it seems like whatever the outermost tag is has to be disregarded in the XPath expression when looking for the configuration items I need.

Why is that?  Is this by design?  Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  In [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/), it is by design that the root is ignored in specifying keys.   Consider this example from the [Apache Commons Config User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html#Accessing_properties_in_hierarchical_configurations):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<gui-definition>
  <colors>
    <background>#808080</background>
    <text>#000000</text>
    <header>#008000</header>
    <link normal="#000080" visited="#800080"/>
    <default>${colors.header}</default>
  </colors>
  <rowsPerPage>15</rowsPerPage>
  <buttons>
    <name>OK,Cancel,Help</name>
  </buttons>
  <numberFormat pattern="###\,###.##"/>
</gui-definition>
```

And the following affirmation that the root is ignored:

> The root element is ignored when constructing keys. In the example you
>   do not write gui-definition.color.text, but only color.text.

Be assured that you are not alone in wondering about this, especially with XPath keys.  But at least it's consistent.  For this XML document,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<database>
  <tables>
    <table tableType="system">
```

[XPaths have to ignore the root element too](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html#The_XPATH_expression_engine):

```
HierarchicalConfiguration config = ...
config.setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());

// Now we can use XPATH queries:
List<Object> fields = config.getList("tables/table[1]/fields/name");
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it - I was in too much of a hurry and didn't read that tutorial thoroughly.

But, it's clear now.  Still slightly counter-intuitive I think, but as long as it's consistent, I'm happy!